# How to correctly refresh data in a grid using Task in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, devexpress, task

My small WPF code is giving me this error 
**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it**
I know what exactly it is saying but I am unable to understand how can I fix it. I have tried different things but no luck and I admit that I am not good in Task library.

This is what I am trying to achieve.

1. Load data when WPF form loads - **This is ok**
2. On the form user will press the **Refresh** button to refresh the data from the database.

here is my code

```
public partial class DocListView : UserControlListBase
{
    private ScecoBillDataScope _scecoBillDataScope;
    public EntityCollection<ScecoBillEntity> ScecoBills = new EntityCollection<ScecoBillEntity>();

   public DocListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }


   private async void LoadData()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            _scecoBillDataScope.FetchData();
        });
        var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_scecoBillDataScope.ScecoBills);

        await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(()=> LayoutRoot.DataContext = collectionView));

     }

  private void BbiRefresh_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        _scecoBillDataScope.Reset();
        LoadData();
        e.Handled = true;
    }}
```

Actually the error is appearing when I click the Refresh button at this line  **_scecoBillDataScope.FetchData();**
Please advice.

Comment: Task.Run(() => return FetchDataFromDB();).ContinueWith((o) => Update your UI with o.Result)

Comment: Your FetchData() method should not try to update any Controls owned by other threads.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada as you suggested, I did this change but still no luck, is it happening because my collection is INotifyChangedProperty aware.
private async void LoadData()
        {
            var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_scecoBillDataScope.ScecoBills);
            await Task.Run(() => _scecoBillDataScope.FetchData()).ContinueWith((o)=> LayoutRoot.DataContext = collectionView);           

        }

Comment: So what does `FetchData()` actually do?

Comment: @Shax Since your collection items are tied to your view, you have to treat them as part of your UI. Try loading a *new* collection from within `Task.Run`, and then copying them over your existing items while on the UI thread.

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary, your tip worked and no doubt you really understood my problem. Huge thanks for helping me out. Please post this as an answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your collection items are data bound to your view, you have to treat them as part of your UI.

Try loading a new collection from within `Task.Run`, and then copying them over your existing items while on the UI thread. So, the new collection is built on a thread pool thread (`Task.Run`), and then the data-bound collection items are modified from the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(()=> LayoutRoot.DataContext = collectionView));
```

You're just creating a new thread, you have to actually dispatch on the GUI thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = collectionView;
});
```

Comment: no my friend didn't fix my problem, but thanks for taking time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do something in UI Thread.

As You know You can use `Dispatcher` class.

But There is another way to ask something to UI Thread.

```
var uiThread = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // I assumed that It returns boolean value
    _scecoBillDataScope.FetchData();
}).ContinueWith(x =>
{
    // Here you can put the code to work on the UI thread.
    if (x.Result)
    {
          var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_scecoBillDataScope.ScecoBills);
          LayoutRoot.DataContext = collectionView;
    }

}, uiThread);
```

I hope it helps.

thank you.

Comment: no my friend didn't fix my problem, appreciate you taking time in help me out.

Comment: is '_scecoBillDataScope.FetchData();' running on a UI thread?